# Horror anthology-purple cover with "The Open Window" late 80's-early 90's

Tags: story-identification, horror

Every few months I look for this book and I can never find it. I read it when I was a kid in the last 80's-early 90's.

I remember it had a cover with a purple sky and dark trees and a creepy-looking girl standing in the trees. The only story I clearly remember from it is "The Open Window" by Saki. I've gotten links to anthologies that include this story and cannot find it. It's possible the cover has changed since then (if it is still in circulation) and I can't remember a thing about the title. Any help would be appreciated.

It wasn't aimed at kids but I don't remember it being too horrific-just creepy.

Answer (score 4):

ISFDB displays [a number of possible covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?79718), but this one (hardcover, published in 1985) seems closest to your description:

[image]

Comment: This wasn't it, but because of your post I went back to look at google and I found it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

I found it! It's called *[The Mammoth Book of 20th Century Ghost Stories](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2027326.The_Mammoth_Book_of_20th_Century_Ghost_Stories)*. The cover wasn't exactly as I remembered (black sky, not purple, a slightly different cover from the one I read because the edition I found came out later than the one I read) but that's definitely it! I fell down the rabbit hole looking at google again. Thank you for the  help!

[image: Book cover]

Comment: You can accept your own answer (by clicking on the check mark) so that the question no longer shows as unsolved.